# Specify Change Data Capture Entities in Scratch Org Definition

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, change-data-capture

Is it possible to enable and configure change Data Capture for specific entities in a scratch org definition file?

I know that you can add "ChangeDataCapture" to the list of features, but I haven't found anywhere on how to specify which objects are selected.

Answer (score 0):

The specified events are stored under PlatformEventChannelMember.
You can configure the Change Data Capture settings in your Scratch Org. Then from your local CLI use:

```
sf force source retrieve -m PlatformEventChannelMember -u [ALIAS]
```

For example in the case of tracking Case Change events the metadata file looks as follows:

[image: Printscreen of PlatformEventChannelMember metadata file.]

I also found a related question here:
[Include activation of change data capture event in managed package subscriber org](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272050/include-activation-of-change-data-capture-event-in-managed-package-subscriber-or)

Good luck!